# volume keyboard shortcut changed now i cant use my volume buttons

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

i made a volume raise and lower keyboard shortcut then my original volume buttons stopped working i tried making them the shortcut and that wont work because i have to use more than one key in a shortcut cant be a single key , i made the shortcut ctrl+ raise volume button to increase volume now my question is can i edit this in terminal or in the file using scratch so that i can remove the ctrl button and just keep the raise volume button so that it would go back to normal ? i am using elementary please keep the answers detailed yet easy to follow i am new.

Comment: There is a related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/194

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by installing 'Dconf editor' from the AppCentre.

1. Open  this program and go to *org>gnome>settings-daemon>plugins>media-keys*
2. Scroll all the way down to where you find *'volume-down'* and *'volume-up'*.
3. If you click on these you will get a list with options,at the bottom you can toggle the option *'use default value'* to **ON**.

This will revert the keyboard shortcuts back to the original volume keys.